# Can't use $.get to get data from another domain

Tags: jquery, web

In my **localhost**, I create an web application to get data from website, it just contain one character. So I create this:

```
$.get("http://www.website.web.id/data.txt", function(client_req) { 
alert(client_req); 
});
```

But it can't load the data. Why?

Comment: Im willing to bet there's an exception in the console

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross domain jquery get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369577/cross-domain-jquery-get)

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource ????

Comment: unless its JSONP, you're gonna have trouble getting stuff cross-domain, because of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy ..

Comment: ohh thank you. sorry for duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, cross domain issue, you can use JSONP or CORS to overcome this issue, I have posted multiple times on this:

[JQuery JSON Calls To PHP WebService Always Runs "Error" Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685949/jquery-json-calls-to-php-webservice-always-runs-error-callback/20691993#20691993)

[Is there any physical, readable difference between a JSON string and a JSONP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802763/is-there-any-physical-readable-difference-between-a-json-string-and-a-jsonp-str/20802781#20802781)

Comment: Thank you. I'm changing my method now.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, not enough reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a solution for you. See:

[crossdomain.xml for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919305/crossdomain-xml-for-jquery)

I'd advise using JSON for this though -- I know it may not sound like a quick and easy solution, but it's the best solution.

If you're using PHP, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
   $arr = array('example' => 'example data', 'anotherexample' => 'OK', 'userage' => 13);
   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

That'd get it to output the data in JSON. Then in your jQuery, you'd do something like:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.website.web.id/data.php', function(client_req) {
        alert(client_req.example);
        alert(client_req.anotherexample);
        alert(client_req.userage);
    }
});
```

Hope that puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, not enough reputation. :)